# IllegalStateException Subscription to topics, partitions and pattern are mutually exclusive

Tags: java, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api

Need to fetch messages from a Kafka topic, from a particular offset

Stuck cause of IllegalStateException exception at `assign()`

If I do not use `assign()` , then the consumer does not perform seek, as that being a Lazy operation

*Actual purpose*: Need to iterate messages at topic from a pre-decided offset till end. This pre-decided offset is calculated at `markOffset()`

```
static void fetchMessagesFromMarkedOffset() {
    Consumer<Long, String> consumer = ConsumerCreator.createConsumer();
    consumer.assign(set); // <---- Exception at this place
    map.forEach((k,v) -> {
        consumer.seek(k, v-3);
    });
    ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(100);
    consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
        System.out.println("Record Key " + record.key());
        System.out.println("Record value " + record.value());
        System.out.println("Record partition " + record.partition());
        System.out.println("Record offset " + record.offset());
    });
    consumer.close();
}
```

Rest of concerned code involved

```
public static Set<TopicPartition> set;
public static Map<TopicPartition, Long> map;

static void markOffset() {
    Consumer<Long, String> consumer = ConsumerCreator.createConsumer();
    consumer.poll(100);
    set = consumer.assignment();
    map = consumer.endOffsets(set);
    System.out.println("Topic  Partitions: " + set);
    System.out.println("End Offsets: " + map);
}
```

Consumer Creation

```
private Consumer createConsumer(String topicName) {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "capacity-service-application");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

    final Consumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));
    return consumer;
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subscription to topics, partitions and pattern are mutually exclusive
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.setSubscriptionType(SubscriptionState.java:104)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignFromUser(SubscriptionState.java:157)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign(KafkaConsumer.java:1064)
at com.gaurav.kafka.App.fetchMessagesFromMarkedOffset(App.java:44)
at com.gaurav.kafka.App.main(App.java:30)
```

Comment: can you please edit the question with code for `ConsumerCreator.createConsumer()`. Looks like the assignment of `TopicPartition` is not done properly.

Comment: Also, what is the value of the `set` that is getting printed?

Comment: added consumer creation code too !

Comment: As I am using these methods at controller.. just maintained the Set<TopicPartion> obtained from consumer  ```set = consumer.assignment();``` in that

Comment: Your consumer creation is correct. Are you able to get the right mapping of topic and partition from `consumer.assignment()`? Also, the functions are void methods. Is this `set` variable static one? how is `set` passing to  `fetchMessagesFromMarkedOffset` method. Where are you assigning the value of offset from which you want to read?

Answer (score 10):

You can't mixed `manual` and `automatic` partition assignment.
You should use `KafkaConsumer::subscribe` or `KafkaConsumer::assign` but not both.

If after calling `KafkaConsumer::subscribe` you want to switch to `manual` approach you should first call `KafkaConsumer::unsubscribe`.

According to https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

> Note that it isn't possible to mix manual partition assignment (i.e. using assign) with dynamic partition assignment through topic subscription (i.e. using subscribe).

Comment: If I create 2 consumer instances, passing same properties, on same topic. Will these have similar partition structures, or could be different ?

Comment: What do you mean by `similar partition structure`? The question is how partition assignment you would need? Manually or automatically?. If you call `assign` you don't use group management.

Comment: Explained it further here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133144/partition-structure-for-2-kafka-consumers-on-same-topic